# Get method name of web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soapui

I use [SoapExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx) to handle asmx web services and store request/response xml into database, here is my web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public DemoResponse demoService(DemoRequest demoRequest)
{
}
```

How to get method name of web service [expect: **`demoService`** ]

I use [soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) to send request

Comment: Are you using SOAP or REST? If it is soap, do want to get the operation of the particular request?

Comment: #Rao: yes, I'm using SOAP

Comment: #Rao: for 2nd question: yes, I want to get the operation name in soapExtension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, we can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["SoapAction"]
```